# Can the image of a spacetime geodesic be characterized through Synge's world function?

Tags: spacetime, geodesics, metric-space

Since a [geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) is understood to be a map $\gamma : \text{real number interval} \rightarrow \text{spacetime } \mathcal S$, with certain additional properties, the image of a particular geodesic is some particular subset of spacetime, i.e. some particular set of events $\mathcal C_{\gamma} \subset \mathcal S$.

The geodesic $\gamma$ provides a certain one-to-one parametrization of its image, $\text{real number interval} \longleftrightarrow \mathcal C_{\gamma}$, while the set of events $\mathcal C_{\gamma}$ itself stands without any particular parametrization or labelling of its elements; it is (overtly) parametrization-independent.

An image of a spacetime geodesic, such as set $\mathcal C_{\gamma}$ as image of geodesic $\gamma$, surely has certain additional properties itself -- besides a suitable cardinality it surely has certain geometric properties. (Therefore any arbitrary event set, even of suitable cardinality, could not be the image of a spacetime geodesic.)

Now, a particular way to express geometric properties of a set of events (and notably invariant under reparametrization) is through values of [Synge's world function $\sigma : \mathcal S \times \mathcal S \rightarrow \mathbb R$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synge%27s_world_function), which are assigned to certain pairs (i.e. to some, but not necessarily to all pairs) of events of a given spacetime $\mathcal S$.

**My question:**
Can the geometric properties of the image of a spacetime geodesic be correctly and fully expressed in terms of values $\sigma$ of Synge's world function?
(And if so, how?)

Specificly:

Is a set of events $\mathcal E$ the image of a spacetime geodesic (or in other words: is $\mathcal E \equiv \mathcal C_{\gamma}$ for some geodesic $\gamma$) if:

- set $\mathcal E$ is identified by three distinct (but not unique) events $a, b, c \in \mathcal E$ for which there exist pairwise assigned values $\sigma[ \, a, b \, ]$ and $\sigma[ \, a, c \, ]$, and $\sigma[ \, b, c \, ]$, and which are straight wrt. each other, i.e. (by [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula))
  $ 2 \, \sigma[ \, a, b \, ] \, \sigma[ \, a, c \, ] + 2 \, \sigma[ \, a, b \, ] \, \sigma[ \, b, c \, ] + 2 \, \sigma[ \, a, c \, ] \, \sigma[ \, b, c \, ] = $
  $ \qquad, \qquad \qquad (\sigma[ \, a, b \, ])^2 + (\sigma[ \, a, c \, ])^2 + (\sigma[ \, b, c \, ])^2$,
- there is a familiy $\{ \mathcal F_i \}$ of sets of events, each of which satisfies the following conditions:
- $a, b, c \in \mathcal F_i$

**and**

- $ \forall e \in \mathcal F_i : $
  $ \exists \, p, q \in \mathcal F_i | e \not\equiv p$ and $e \not\equiv q$ and $p \not\equiv q$ and $\exists \, \sigma[ \, e, p \, ]$ and $\exists \, \sigma[ \, e, q \, ]$ and $\exists \, \sigma[ \, p, q \, ]$

**and**

- $ \forall j, k, n \in \mathcal F_i : $
  **if** $ \exists \, \sigma[ \, j, k \, ], \sigma[ \, j, n \, ], \sigma[ \, k, n \, ]$
  **then** $ 2 \, \sigma[ \, j, k \, ] \, \sigma[ \, j, n \, ] + 2 \, \sigma[ \, j, k \, ] \, \sigma[ \, k, n \, ] + 2 \, \sigma[ \, j, n \, ] \, \sigma[ \, k, n \, ] = $
  $ \qquad \qquad \qquad (\sigma[ \, j, k \, ])^2 + (\sigma[ \, j, n \, ])^2 + (\sigma[ \, k, n \, ])^2$

**and**

- $ \forall x, y \in \mathcal F_i : $
  **if** $x \not\equiv y$ and $\exists \, \sigma[ \, x, y \, ]$ and $\exists \, z$ and $\exists \, \sigma[ \, x, z \, ]$ and $\exists \, \sigma[ \, y, z \, ]$ and
  $ 2 \, \sigma[ \, x, y \, ] \, \sigma[ \, x, z \, ] + 2 \, \sigma[ \, x, y \, ] \, \sigma[ \, y, z \, ] + 2 \, \sigma[ \, x, z \, ] \, \sigma[ \, y, z \, ] = $
  $ \qquad \qquad \qquad (\sigma[ \, x, y \, ])^2 + (\sigma[ \, x, z \, ])^2 + (\sigma[ \, y, z \, ])^2$
  **then** $z \in \mathcal F_i$.
- Finally: $ \mathcal E := \text{Intersection}[ \, \{ \mathcal F_i \} \, ]$

?

Comment: Given a Cauchy normal neighbourhood, the geodesic between two points $p,q$ is going to be the curve that minimize (or maximize, depending on the sign) the world function $\sigma(p,q)$. You can cover your curve with an appropriate number of such neighbourhoods to span its entire length (I am assuming here that you're using a Levi-Civita connection, otherwise this may not work).

Comment: @Slereah: "_Given [...] the geodesic between two points $p,q$ is going to be the curve that minimize (or maximize) the world function_" -- That's imprecise and puzzling (to me). If (under suitable "_given_" circumstances) $\sigma[ \, p, q \, ]$ is defined, then it has a definite fixed value (apart perhaps from some overall nonzero proportionality). These suitable "_given_" circumstances include that there is a unique geodesic connecting $p,q$, with signed arclength $$\text{Sgn}[ \, \sigma[ \, p, q \, ] \, ] * \sqrt{ \sigma[ \, p, q \, ] * \text{Sgn}[ \, \sigma[ \, p, q \, ] \, ] }.$$

Comment: @Slereah: "_You can cover your curve with an appropriate number of such neighbourhoods to span its entire length_" -- Right, I'm most concerned about the case of no $\sigma$-value defined for $p,q$. So: Do you mean the answer to my "specific question" is: "Yes." ? "_(I am assuming here that [...], otherwise this may not work)._" -- I'm assuming $\sigma$-values as they come. Do you know circumstances in which there aren't any $\sigma$-values available at all (perhaps except $\sigma[ \, p, p \, ] = 0, \sigma[ \, q, q \, ] = 0$ etc.), yet geodesics could be defined and spoken of anyways ?